# Why does Angular CLI scripts property not work for CKEditor?

Tags: angular

In my Angular[24] app I am using ng2-ckeditor. To make it work I had to add the following to my **index.html** file:

```
<script src="./assets/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

(Since there seems to no npm package to install the editor itself I downloaded the current zip file and unzipped it in ./assets/js.)

Reading the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli#project-assets) this should have been included in the **.angular-cli.json** file in the **scripts** property like this:

```
(snip)  
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "./assets/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
  ],
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  (snip)
```

But if I remove the HTML tag above and do that it doesn't work.

Should this have been done through the JSON file and if so what would I have been doing wrong?

Comment: didnt quiet understood you. There is npm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor. for script you have to write that in your angular-cli.json. then all u have to do is use this in template ` <ckeditor></ckeditor>`

Comment: this should work just fine. What version of the cli are you using?

Comment: @ParthGhiya look at the documentation for ng2-ckeditor.  It says to install the following in your index.html file: <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js"></script> The URL is remote.  I wanted the scripts in local resource.

Comment: @alan: you will find it in node modules folder

Comment: Did you ever get this working inside of your assets folder? I am running customizations that require we use a static version in my asset path. After upgrading to Angular-ClI and Angular 6 it's having problems loading.

If so what was your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do

   ```
   npm install ckeditor --save
   ```
2. change your  .angular-cli.json

   ```
   "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
   ],
   ```

Comment: This part of it seems to work but I still have problems which are too complex to list here.  I will have to enter a new question.   I get console log messages to the effect that it can't load the resource.